# Chrome failed to start in ubuntu without windows

Tags: python, selenium

I use selenium in a ubuntu virtual machine without windows. But there's something wrong with that.Anyone can give me a hand.

```
import os
from selenium import webdriver
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
display = Display(visible=0, size=(800, 600))
display.start()
chrome_driver = os.path.abspath(r"/opt/selenium/chromedriver")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_driver)
driver.get("http://www.google.com/")
print driver.page_source.encode('utf-8')
driver.quit()
display.stop()
```

and i get this exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 9, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_driver)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 69, in __init__
    desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 92, in __init__
    self.start_session(desired_capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 179, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, capabilities)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 236, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 192, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: crashed
   (Driver info: chromedriver=2.26.436382 (70eb799287ce4c2208441fc057053a5b07ceabac),platform=Linux 3.10.0-327.36.2.el7.x86_64 x86_64)
```

Comment: this code works for me - Linux Mint 17 (based on Ubuntu 14.04), ChromeDriver 2.25.426924, Chromium  53.0.2785.143

Comment: I test with ChromeDriver 2.26.436382  and works too. Python 2.7.12 & 3.5.2. Selenium 3.0.1, pyvirtualdisplay 0.2.1

Comment: @furas ok,I'll try again

Comment: @furas I tried again,but also did not work.I tested in a docker container based Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS. Or ,do you konw any images of docker can be used directly

Comment: do you have `Chrome` browser (`Chromium`) installed in docker ? As I know Ubuntu doesn't have this browser as default.

Comment: @furas yeah,I tried chrome-stable and chromium both,but no one can be used.

Comment: @furas I'm going to be crazy. I tried Firefox, it worked,but Chrome did't.  Embarrassed!!!

Comment: Nothing strange - I had no problem with Chrome but Firefox doesn't work for me with Selenium - I need drivers for Firefox, etc..